# Trivial point about tex.se vs. tex.sx

Tags: discussion

Most folk seem to prefer tex.se to tex.sx as our interim name, but:

1. .se is an actual country code and .sx is not any kind of top-level domain; and
2. tex.se is a registered, though unused domain:

   ```
   state:            active
   domain:           tex.se
   holder:           tradee0702-00002
   admin-c:          -
   tech-c:           -
   billing-c:        -
   created:          2003-04-26
   modified:         2010-04-10
   expires:          2011-04-26
   nserver:          -
   dnssec:           unsigned delegation
   status:           inactive
   registrar:        SE Direkt
   ```

It's really trivial, since there's no real risk of ambiguity, but for some reason using tex.se agitates me...  I'd be more grateful than I should be if we could favour tex.sx.

Comment: Maybe I've been too much out of the loop lately, but what is this "interim name" for?

Comment: @Juan: Gossiping about the site.  It's really trivial, I'm sorry, but try googling [site:tex.stackexchange.com (+"tex.se" OR +"tex.sx")](http://www.google.de/search?q=site%3Atex.stackexchange.com+%28%2B"tex.se"+OR+%2B"tex.sx"%29).

Answer (score 4):

Guilty as charged, and being resident in Norway I Should Know Better.  I hereby resolve to Change My Ways.

Comment: I just assumed that we all knew better but didn't care. Maybe when it expires, someone can grab tex.se and point it here.

Comment: @TH. It seems www.tex.se is registered by a [Swedish domain company](http://www.sedirekt.se/en/) that adds extends the domain expiration date for a year each year. Next time will be 2012-04-26: http://whois.domaintools.com/tex.se