# Off-topic closure: migration paths

Tags: discussion, close-reasons, migration

In a [related post](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/3644/off-topic-closure-predefined-reasons) I've asked (again) about custom 'off-topic' closure texts. As I note there, the second thing we need to address if  closing as off-topic is a reasonable set of places on the StackExchange network that questions might be migrated to.

Moderators can migrate questions to *any* other network site, but for normal users only predefined migration paths are available. So what we need to do is decide what those paths should be. I'm not sure how many we are allowed, but I think up to say three 'common' cases would be a reasonable request to the Powers.

What I think I'm after here is one migration path per answer, with a reason why it would be useful (say one or two examples).

Comment: Note that we don't currently seem to migrate much away at all: a look over the stats shows 13 questions moved away in the last 90 days. I suspect this might be partly 'chicken and egg' (as for non-mods there are no migration paths).

Comment: Is there a way how our powerseach can seach for migrated questions? I think that I was flagging for migration couple times and suggesting it, but I don't seem to be able to find it.

Comment: @tohecz The is `migrated:no` (and presumably `:yes`) in the search tips, but I'm not sure how effective it is.

Comment: Well, [it shows exactly 3 posts](http://tex.stackexchange.com/search?q=migrated%3Ayes) :-/

Comment: @tohecz I thought migrated questions are deleted here?

Comment: @mafp Looks like it: searching for [migrated and deleted](http://tex.stackexchange.com/search?q=migrated%3Ayes+deleted%3Ayes) shows 66 hits for me (may be mod-only!).

Comment: @JosephWright There's some mod/20k power that allows it... I'll try to get my 2.5k ASAP and see if I see them then ;)