# Off topic close reason no longer available

Tags: feature-request, close-reasons

I noticed that a reason has been added in the Close Question dialog, in the category *A community-specific reason*:

[image]

This reason is for non-reproducible or trivial questions, and it suggests to add an MWE.

I assume the close reasons have been modified by our own moderators (instead of by Stack Exchange the company, see https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/396597/ for an explanation of this new feature). I do like the new reason (although I think that *non-reproducible* and *trivial* should be two different reasons, but that is not the point of my current question). However, it seems to have replaced the old reason "this is not about TeX, LaTeX etc".

So what is currently the right option to select if a question is about something else and not related to LaTeX at all? For some cases "belongs on another site" could be appropriate, however, this option leads to another screen where you can only choose our own Meta and not for example Stack Overflow or Math.SE or Academia.SE or Super User. For other off-topic questions there is no other appropriate site, so even if there would be more sites available to choose from this would not be a good solution in general. So should we use Other - add a comment? If so, could we have the old reason back, and the new one as an additional option?

---

Following the comment by moderator Joseph Wright below, I suggest to add the following close reason (which is the same as the formerly available reason) to the *A community-specific reason* menu:

> This question does not fall within the scope of TeX, LaTeX or related typesetting systems as defined in the [help center](https://tex.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic).

Comment: yes I noticed that the other day and chose other and suggested stackoverflow in the comment, seems a bit poor really but we have never been able to suggest migration to other sites.

Comment: This looks a little like a custom text suggested many years ago by the Powers, but it's not the same, nor have the local mods set it up as far as I know: I wonder when this popped up!

Comment: We can request other targets for off-topic, but most of the time flagging is OK as the mods can migrate anywhere. we've never got a consensus on one or two 'main' targets

Comment: @JosephWright so do you suggest to keep the current options and choose Other for off-topic? Or do you plan to re-introduce a separate off-topic reason?

Comment: @Marijn The only local control I have is to add additional or modified local statements: suggestions are welcome

Comment: @JosephWright I have added a suggestion to the post.

Comment: @JosephWright I guess it came from [here](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/7305/). Perhaps it has been set at that time. (inactive until now) Disabling may restore the default text. Though adding some gives more flexibility.

Comment: @JosephWright any news on this? Today I saw that the off-topic close reason still isn't available. Of course you might be on holiday or busy doing other things, in that case enjoy your time and address it later :)