# Why isn't there the possibility of closing a question for being off-topic?

Tags: support, close-reasons

This question is probably a duplicate, but since I was unable to find one, here it goes.

On any other Stack Exchange site that I use, if you click the `Close` link under a question and then you choose `A community-specific reason`, the first option that you get is that the question is not within the scope of that site. In our case, that would mean that the question is not TeX-related. However, our first option is that the problem is not reproducible or that it is due to a typographical error. And there isn't the option of closing for not being within the scope of our site. Of course, an user can always choose the `Other - add a comment` option (and many do), but why isn't it part of the canned options?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

We had a discussion about close reasons here: [Text for 'off-topic' closure](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/3632/text-for-off-topic-closure). It seems that it wasn't completely discussed and finished.

I activated an off-topic text, that was already prepared:

> This question does not fall within the scope of TeX-LaTeX Stack Exchange as defined in the [help center](https://tex.stackexchange.com/help). These reasons may include the use of out of date packages/distributions, bug reports or simple typing errors. The comments on the question should describe the main reason.

It appears within the community specific close reasons, as off-topic is community specific.

Comment: It was discussed also more recently on https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/8633/off-topic-close-reason-no-longer-available. The text suggested there (which was the same as the wording prior to last year's updates) was _This question does not fall within the scope of TeX, LaTeX or related typesetting systems as defined in the [help center](https://tex.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic)_. I prefer that version because it is more general and allows for more specific information to be presented in the help center. The wording in the answer above is only a subset of [...]

Comment: [...] reasons for being off-topic, notably excluding the reason that a question is not about LaTeX or similar. There are many off-topic questions asking about mathematical notation conventions, font identification, MathJax, etc. I would like the off-topic close reason to include such cases, which may be easiest by not mentioning specific possible reasons at all and using the help center for further information.