# What should be the acronym for tex.stackexchange.com?

Tags: discussion

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Trivial point about tex.se vs. tex.sx](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/470/trivial-point-about-tex-se-vs-tex-sx)

The TeX community places significant *emphasis* on notations and pronunciations. Therefore, risking negative votes for two obvious reasons (some might think this question is more suited for meta; others might think the question is too trivial), I must ask this question. What should be the acronym for tex.stackexchange.com?

This question is not all that irrelevant as it may seem. Many questions, answers and blog posts refer to this website in confusing acronyms, which I have taken a few seconds to realize what they were referring to.

Comment: I think TeX.SE is most common one I have seen.

Comment: Well Stack.SE is the most common for any stack. But TeXers  wanting to add a bit of "TeX" to the convention, have also adopted TeX.SX in the common conversations. I just wonder why haven't they gone all the way through.

Comment: I've migrated this from the main site to meta, as it's about the site itself rather than using TeX.

Comment: This looks like the existing [Trivial point about tex.se vs. tex.sx](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/470)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Across the StackExchange network, the 'standard' short forms all take the form '<*site*>.SE', and in our case that means 'TeX.SE'. That tends to be the best choice is talking to people familiar with other network sites or communicating *via* channels such as StackExchange staff.

Within the site (i.e. when viewing it independent of the StackExchange network), the general consensus has been that 'TeX.SX', 'TeX.sx', 'TeX-SX', 'TeX-sx' are all sensible forms, to be read as 'TeX Stack Exchange'. For example, in the [Text building blocks](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/430/text-building-blocks) the style is (currently) 'TeX.sx'. Note that using 'TeX.SE' is also entirely fine on the site (*i.e.* there is no 'official' position on this.)

Comment: I agree. I got "funny looks" when I used TeX.SX on the main Meta site or in other chat rooms. TeX.SE is the "official" short form. However, I learned that words starting with 'ex' are often shorten to 'x', not 'e', so I was surprised that people had an issue with TeX.SX.

Answer (score 1):

My personal choice is:
TeX.SeX
(of course it has to be pronounced correctly the way LaTeX is pronounced).

Comment: Oh, the Freudian (La)TeX.stackexchange! I can't help it, something completely different comes to my mind, when I see this... `:)`

Comment: Well, even LaTeX can mean something entirely different. But saying it again and again has fixed it my brain: LaTe(ch). I guess I will be saying "(ach)-Men" and so on and so forth... :)

Comment: The SeX of TeX.